# Finding extra persons and in which category they belong

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a script for a hotel with my little knowledge in PHP where the user (me) selects how many persons are about to rent a room.

All of my rooms are for 2 persons.  Depending on how many there are, I'm charging an extra price/day, per person.  More can stay, but those "extras" will have to pay depending on the age.

```
function calc()
{
    $data['msg'] = "";
    $data['from_date'] = $this->input->post('from_date');
    $data['to_date'] = $this->input->post('to_date');
    $data['category'] = $this->input->post('category');
    $data['guestid'] = $this->input->post('guestid');
    $data['idroom'] = $this->input->post('room');

    $data['nguests'] = $this->input->post('nguests');
    $data['nchilds'] = $this->input->post('nchilds');
    $data['lchilds'] = $this->input->post('lchilds');

    $data['greek'] = $this->input->post('greek');
    $data['continental'] = $this->input->post('continental');
    $data['halfboard'] = $this->input->post('halfboard');
    $data['whitewine'] = $this->input->post('whitewine');
    $data['redwine'] = $this->input->post('redwine');

    $data['preferences'] = $this->input->post('preferences');
    $data['mandiscount'] = $this->input->post('mandiscount');

    $data['booking'] = $this->input->post('booking');
    $data['airport'] = $this->input->post('airport');
    $data['annotation'] = $this->input->post('annotation');

    $data['is_manual'] = $this->input->post('is_manual');

    if($data['is_manual'] == "manual")
    {
        $data['price_per_day'] = $this->input->post('price_per_day');
    }

    $room_avail = $this->kratiseis->getRoomPrice($data['idroom'], $data['from_date'], $data['to_date']);
    $category_details = $this->admin->getSingleRoomCategory($data['category']);
    $extras = $this->admin->getExtras();
    $client = $this->guests->details($data['guestid']);
    $data['room'] = $this->details->getSingleRoom($data['idroom']);

    //$stay_days = date_diff($data['from_date'], $data['to_date']) - 1;

    $from = new DateTime($this->input->post('from_date'));
    $to = new DateTime($this->input->post('to_date'));
    $stay_days = $from->diff($to);
    $data['stay_for'] = $stay_days->format('%d');

    $data['total_guests'] = $data['nguests'] + $data['nchilds'] + $data['lchilds'];

    /*
     * We only accept 2 persons in any room.  If there are more than 2, we charge extra
     */

    $extra_adults_price = 0;
    $extra_childs_price = 0;
    $extra_adults = 0;
    $extra_childs = 0;
    $we_have_extras = false;

    if($data['total_guests'] > 2)
    {
        /*
         * Find how many adults extra we have.
         */
        if($data['nguests'] > 2)
        {
            $we_have_extras = true;
            $extra_adults = $data['nguests'] - 2;
            $extra_adults_price = ($extra_adults * $data['stay_for']) * 10;
        }

        /*
         * Find how many extra children do we have.
         */
        if( $data['nchilds'] > 2)
        {
            $we_have_extras = true;
            $extra_childs = $data['nchilds'] - 2;
            $extra_childs_price = ($extra_childs * $data['stay_for']) * 5;
        }
    }
```

Here's the view, from where I get the data:

```
<div class="column-container">
    <div class="column column-1" style="background-color: #097ea1; color: #fff;">Adults:</div>
    <div class="column column-2" style="background-color: #cee8ef">
        <select name="nguests">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-3" style="background-color: #097ea1; color: #fff;">Children 0-5:</div>
    <div class="column column-4" style="background-color: #cee8ef">
        <select name="nchilds">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-5" style="background-color: #097ea1; color: #fff;">Children 6-12:</div>
    <div class="column column-6" style="background-color: #cee8ef">
        <select name="lchilds">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-7"></div>
    <div class="column column-8"></div>
</div>
```

I also have some code in the controller.

Now, lets say we have a reservation of 3 adults + 1 child = total of 4 persons.  The extra cost is $10, but it should have been $15 (10 for the adult and 5 for the child)

How can I distinguish those values of extra persons so I can get my desired result?

Comment: Do you have some flag to say that an extra person is adult or child?

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez What do you mean by that ? :)  
All values are from a form.  
The user selects how many adults (1-4) and how many childs (0-4) are about to come.

Comment: Can you paste your html form here? Seeing it will be easier

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez I've edited my post with code above, thanks for your time :)

Comment: You need some defaults. Example: If you have 2 adults and some chilldren, always the main persons will be adults? You need to create some rules about it. Do you got it?

Comment: Yes, in that case we will  consider the child as the extra person.
If we have 3 adults and one children, then the extras will be 1 adult and one child. In case there are 1 adult + 2 kids, then the extra is the 1 kid.

Comment: Is in case of 2 adults and 1 child always calculated two adults as room taker or it can be adult + child as room taker and second adult as extra? Is there price difference in these two approaches?

Comment: @Tpojka 2 Adults are ok, the child its extra :D

Comment: As Márcio Gonzalez pointed, here is need for defined rules. So two adults will always be room taker in case 1 adult is in the room no matter how many person is there? Answer to that and you'll get the answer. Don't forget that adult with child can take room too.

Comment: Here's the logic:
Every room has 2 persons capacity. Either is 2 adults, or 1 adult+1child. There always will be one adult in the room.
In any case, all i want is to do, is to charge the 3rd person, and define witch one of those 2 it is, adult or child?

Have i confused you that much? I am... :D

Comment: @johnny-bones Thank you for the corrections :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I think the problem is in your logic

```
Function  CountExtras($data) {      
if($data['total_guests'] <= 2) return 0;

$extra_adults_price = 0;
$extra_childs_price = 0;
$extra_adults = 0;
$extra_childs = 0;

$data['nguests'] = $data['total_guests'] - $data['nchilds'];

If( $data['nguests'] >= 2  )  $data['nguests'] = $data['nguests'] - 2; 
else {
    $data['nguests'] = 0;
    --$data['nchilds'];
}

return $data['nguests']*10 + $data['nchilds']*5;
}

echo CountExtras(array ( 'total_guests' => 1, 'nchilds' => 0 )).'<br>'; // 0
echo CountExtras(array ( 'total_guests' => 2, 'nchilds' => 0 )).'<br>'; // 0
echo CountExtras(array ( 'total_guests' => 3, 'nchilds' => 1 )).'<br>'; // 5 
echo CountExtras(array ( 'total_guests' => 3, 'nchilds' => 0 )).'<br>'; // 10
echo CountExtras(array ( 'total_guests' => 4, 'nchilds' => 1 )).'<br>'; // 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, may i ask what does `--$data['nchilds'];` do? :P

Comment: $data['nchilds'] =  $data['nchilds'] - 1;

Comment: @tsompanis  if the code works as you want, don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Yea, i am aware. :) I didn't had time to test you'r code, but i have now. Unfortunately i don't get the results i'm expecting. If you read the comments above you will understand better i guess since i explained more. You'r code seems to work fine, but IF and ONLY the adults are 2+
If we have 1 adult, then it doesn't. Have a look at [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/Pq6V7qSt) . Ofc i have made some _minor_ edits :)

Comment: @tsompanis I've extended the answer not changing the function. Does it not that what you want?

Comment: Looks like it does. I will try to implement it and test it some more in my program. Ill get back to you with a vote up and an accepted answer if it works :) Thank you for the moment :)

Comment: With tiny changes to fit my code. It worked. At least it looks like it did :)
THANK YOU! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Room price room is basicly same for any first two persons. I think you are exaggregate here. You already collect strict number of additional room users.
I am not sure why don't you use basic algebra to calculate it , because you collect specific data in each form input field. I.e. if someone set 2 extraAdults it need to be calculated as that:

```
$price = $this->roomPrice;//some basic value for two persons
$price += ( (int)$this->input->post('extraAdults') > 0 ) ? (int)$this->input->post('extraAdults') * 10 : 0;
$price += ( (int)$this->input->post('extraChild') > 0 ) ? (int)$this->input->post('extraChild') * 5 : 0;
//var_dump($price);
```